# Grouping Data in Report Builder and adding a calculated field

Tags: reporting-services, report, grouping, reportbuilder3.0

I have the following query output from SQL:
[Query and Report Formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAVY0.jpg)

I have managed to restrain my data for the first columns but I don't know how to show the values as in the example in the last column named "Return"

The logic behind the completion of the "Return" column is the following:

After I group the data by the unique combination Section_ID x Route_ID: 
If I have a return on the Section_ID the value of the "Return" column should be "Yes", else if there are not return it should be "No".

How can I achieve the report output as in the picture?

Thanks.

Comment: It is very possible to get the result you want, but don't understand the logic to produce Yes and No returns. From your question I understood if there is a Yes in the Section-Route combination the logic should return Yes otherwise No but I see in your example there are two rows for Section 6 and Route 25, both have No but you put Yes, why? Explain in detail.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I completed the return column wrong. There should be a "No" value there. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LookupSet()` and `Join()` functions to get all returns by `Section` and `Route` combination in a string. Once you have all returns you can use the `InStr()` function to check if there is at least one return and return `Yes` in that case, otherwise return `No`.

So I've used the following expression:

```
=IIF(
InStr(Join(LookupSet(Fields!SectionID.Value & "-" & Fields!RouteID.Value,
Fields!SectionID.Value & "-" & Fields!RouteID.Value,
Fields!Return.Value,"DataSet25"),","),"Yes")>0,"Yes","No"
)
```

Based on the data returned by your query I've recreated your example, this is the result.

[image]

Note there are two rows for Section 4 and Route 26 combination, the expression returns `Yes` because one of the rows has a return.

Let me know if this helps.